# Content Security Policy wildcard seems to be ignored

Tags: electron, content-security-policy

To give some context, this is an Electron app, loading the index.html using file://

It seems like the content security policy is contracting itself:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://o944978.ingest.sentry.io/api/5893671/envelope/?sentry_key=0a6134a5d89d40c4954c6144b0e63c64&sentry_version=7' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: *.sentry.io *.cloudfront.net". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

That URL clearly matches the wildcard *.sentry.io, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer myself here: You can't.

The 2 options are: disabling web security or starting a static web server.

Answer (score 1):

The `*.sentry.io` source is [recomended by `docs.sentry.io`](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/cdn/#content-security-policy) docs and it definitely should work even you put it in `default-src` directive instead of `connect-src` one. CSP supports wilcard to specify a subdomains.

The only reason why CSP can block allowed sources is the presence of browser plugins like NoScript/uBlock and so on.

Comment: Thanks, look at my answer, the issue is that I'm doing this from a filesystem URL and you simply cannot access HTTPS from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing your implementation, but here are some suggestions:

1. Test using only *.sentry.io in the CSP at first; add domains as they appear in the errors. This idea is to come up with the minimal CSP that makes it work.
2. My CSP has "data:" at the end of the list. I don't remember why, but I think there was a reason...
3. Make sure you are closing each list with a semicolon ";"

(Answered as a post because I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion trying to help:

Could you try also **explicitly setting the `connect-src`** with

```
connect-src sentry.io https://*.sentry.io *.sentry.io;
```

(and maybe other needed hosts)

#### Do you still get this error?

Comment: Thanks, look at my answer, the issue is that I'm doing this from a filesystem URL and you simply cannot access HTTPS from there.